# R How do I convert a file organised in rows into a set of matrices-one for each row

Tags: r, file, matrix, transpose

I have 2 files that have corresponding X and Y values each contain the values in rows and there are 100 rows and 50 values in each. I at first used a read.table command to read each file into a variable, "X and Y". Now I have to make each row into it's own matrix (with one column) and then bind them so that the 50 Xs and 50 Ys will line up i.e. the matrix made from the first row of X values will line up with that of the first row in the Y coordinates. 
After transposing the X and Y so that the rows would become columns ( I thought that would be easier) I tried converting them to matrices in a for loop with:

```
    for(i in 1:49){
       x<-as.matrix(trajx[,i])#specifying i in columns-variable was transposed
       x<-cbind(x, as.matrix(trajy[,i]))
    }
```

However this only returns two 50-long columns and the values seem totally randomly selected from the X and Y datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You may want first transform the data frames into matrices, and then pick *rows*, not columns:

```
X <- as.matrix(X) # improves efficiency
Y <- as.matrix(Y)
for(i in 1:50) {
   x <- cbind(X[i,], Y[i,]) # note: firs index picks rows
   # note: this x will be be overwritten during the next loop
}
```

(untested)  If you want to save all 50 matrices, you may want to add lines `x <- vector("list", 50)` before the loop, and `x[[i]] <- ...` instead of `x <- ...` in the loop.

Comment: perfect thanks very much I'm also trying to label the consecutive now bound columns as X and Y

Comment: write.table(x, append=F, sep=",",row.names=T,col.names=c("X","Y")) I was going to use the following command but but it returns "Error: invalid columns specification"

Comment: The you write: `x <- cbind(X=X[i,], Y=Y[i,])`

Comment: yeah "x[[i]] <- cbind(X=X[i,], Y=Y[i,])" returns a continuous stream of "+" signs producing more each time I press Enter...

Comment: trajx<-read.table("dataCondition01PosX.txt")
               trajy<-read.table("dataContition01PosY.txt")
               X <- as.matrix(trajx)
               Y <- as.matrix(trajy)
               x <- vector("list", 50)
               for(i in 1:50) {
               x[[i]] <- cbind(X[i,], Y[i,])
                }

Comment: Hmm..  look like correct.  The form I suggested above--`x <- cbind(X=X[i,], Y=Y[i,])` works for me, I cannot understand where do you get the '+' signs from..

Comment: ok thanks anyways... is there any way that I could send someone the original data and my code?